# How to create Post request to Rails API using Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, postman

I am new to Postman. I have a Rails server running on the background. I am trying to mock a POST request, but it is not being accepted.

Let's say the model is called `manufacturer_organization.rb`. Inside, it *requires* 3 parameters: `organization_id (uuid data type), manufacturer_id (integer data type), and account_number (string data type).` `manufacturer_organization` belongs_to organization and it also belongs_to :manufacturer (vice versa; manufacturer and organization has_many manufacturer_organization)

Inside `manufacturer_organizations_controller.rb`, I have a create method:

```
  def create
    @manufacturer_organization = ManufacturerOrganization.new(manufacturer_organization_params)
    if @manufacturer_organization.save
      puts "success!"
      render json: @manufacturer_organization
    else
      puts "Sorry, something went wrong"
    end
  end
```

I can confirm that I have sufficient authorization; when I perform a GET request I got the right JSON response. I am using rails serializer and I have setup serializer for this model as well. Route is also setup using `resources :manufacturer_organizations`. My gut feeling says the way I am using postman is wrong.

Here is the screenshot of Postman app. I have the right address on address bar, and I am performing a POST request. I have the three params under `key-value`.

[image: Postman screenshot POST]

After I `Send` it, under my Rails Server log I see:

```
Started POST "/manufacturer_organizations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-13 16:56:44 -0700
Processing by ManufacturerOrganizationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"organization_id"=>"fb20ddc9-a3ee-47c3-bdd2-f710541-ff89c", "manufacturer_id"=>"1", "account_number"=>"A rand
om account number test"}
...
  (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Sorry, something went wrong
```

I can do `ManufacturerOrganization.new(organization_id: Organization.last.id, manufacturer_id: Manufacturer.last.id, and account_number: "random test account number")` just fine inside `rails console`.

How can I submit a POST request from postman to add a new manufacturer_organization?

**Edit:**

```
  def manufacturer_organization_params
    api_params.permit(:organization_id, :manufacturer_id, :account_number)
  end
```

whereas inside `application_controller.rb`

```
def api_params
    @api_params ||= ActionController::Parameters.new(ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params))
  end
```

**Edit2:**

I added `error.full_messages` and this is what I got:

```
Manufacturer can't be blank
Organization can't be blank
Account number can't be blank
```

Why are they blank?

Comment: show please your `manufacturer_organization_params`

Comment: Hmmm, it looks good. And params passed without problem from postman - problem not in postman, I think

Comment: Print the actual errors in the else instead of the "sorry" message and see what the issue is.

Comment: put @manufacturer_organization_params and let's see the initialize method for ManufacturerOrganization

Comment: Sorry, do you mind elaborating? I added `puts manufacturer_organization_params` on controller and it prints out `<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fc1ce415b80>` while adding `puts @manufacturer_organization_params` prints nothing when I submit POST.

Comment: I m not sure...but just for fun replace `api_params` with `params` in `manufacturer_organization_params` lets see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data using params or within the body request.

The best way to do this is using the body, because you can send files and the request becomes more clean without the params.

To send data in the body, you must pass the model name and attribute in the "key" field, and the value in the "value" field, like this:

[image: See this example image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you do to your *params*. There is a reason the *ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization* is namespaced in the "Model" namespace. It shouldn't be used to serialize or de-serialize internet params, but instead it's for serializing/de-serializing model instances.

If parameters arrive in the correct format *ActionController::Base* from which *AplicationController* and thus *ManufacturerOrganizationsController* inherit will de-serialize them for you. The Rails query parameter format looks as follows:

```
name=something                        #=> params[:name] = 'something'

names[]=something1&names[]=something2 #=> params[:names] = ['something1', 'something2']

instance[id]=1&instance[name]=foo     #=> params[:instance] = {id: '1', name: 'foo'}
```

This can also be stacked and is used for nested resources by Rails. Example:

```
instance[title]=some&instance[nested][name]=thing&instance[nested][ids][]=1&instance[nested][ids][]=2
#=> params[:instance] = {title: 'some', nested: {name: 'thing', ids: ['1', '2']}}
```

Having said that let's get to your example. First of al let us throw away those manual building of params and stick to the convention:

```
class ManufacturerOrganizationsController

  # ...

  private

  def manufacturer_organization_params
    # arriving params should look like this:
    #
    #=> params = {
    #     manufacturer_organization: {
    #       organization_id: 'fb20ddc9-a3ee-47c3-bdd2-f710541-ff89c',
    #       organization_id: '1',
    #       account_number: 'A random account number test'
    #     }
    #   }
    #
    # The method #require raises an exception if the provided key
    # is not present or has a blank value (with exception of false).
    # If the key is found and has a value present than that value is
    # returned.
    #
    params.require(:manufacturer_organization)
          .permit(:organization_id, :manufacturer_id, :account_number)
  end

end
```

With that out of the way let's send the correct formatted params:

```
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Key                                        | Value                                 |
|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
| manufacturer_organization[organization_id] | fb20ddc9-a3ee-47c3-bdd2-f710541-ff89c |
| manufacturer_organization[manufacturer_id] | 1                                     |
| manufacturer_organization[account_number]  | A random account number test          |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Those 2 things combined should let you create your resource successfully.

The key thing you should take from this is that params is not a string containing al the params that should be de-serialized. It already should be de-serialized, if it's not than you might have send your parameters wrong.

Answer (score -1):

## Ruby on Rails and Postman - Post request.

Hello, this is an example that I developed with Postman and Rails API.

### Postman.

I can't add images but this what you have to add in postman **Key** = **Value**
Change to **Post Request** and send.

```
book[name] = 'Harry Potter'
book[author] = J.K. Rowling
```

### Ruby on Rails 7.

Rails maintains the same code.

```
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
      render json: @book, status: :created, location: api_v1_books_url(@book)
    else
      render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def book_params
    debugger
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :price)
  end
```

I hope this helps.